# Need help two While Loops

Tags: python

I'm a beginner. Right now we are learning algorithms. I want to run this in Python. You have to enter a group of 3 numbers and then do an addition of the numbers until the additon equals to 100. But when the additon is not equals to 100 there's like infinite loop. Don't understand.

Forgive my english.

```
suma = 0
n = 1
num = 0

while suma != 100:
    suma = 0
    while n <= 3:
        n = int(n)
        n  = n + 1
        num = input('Ingrese un número: ')
        num = int(num)
        suma = int(suma)
        suma = suma + num
```

Comment: Your loop is not finished because it has to make a 100 exactly addition. Use the "<=" operator instead.

Comment: there's no need for the line `n = int(n)`.  `n` is an `int` to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

you have to reset the value of `n` to ask for input again if the total is not equal to `100`. you got an infinite loop because your program will no longer ask for input because you didn't reset your variable `n` that's why it didn't get inside to your inner loop

like this

```
while suma != 100:
    suma = 0
    n = 1
```

Comment: if the total is 100 the loop has to terminate, but if not, it has to keep me asking for 3 numbers and do the addition until the total is 100

Comment: if you only want to terminate the loop if the total is 100.. then there's no wrong with your code.

Comment: yes. when I enter 3 numbers and the addition of them is equals to 100 the program ends, but if you enter 3 numbers and the addtion is not equals to a 100, it doesnt ask me again to enter other 3 numbers. Instead, the program crahses or something, stays in an infinite loop. I want to keep me asking for 3 new numbers until the addtion hits 100

Comment: i updated my answer. you have to reset the value of your variable `n`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be sum <= 100?

Comment: if the sum will equal to 100. program will still ask for input.. it should stop if the sum will equal to 100